# Call current post parameters inside a plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

I edited the plugin WP User Frontend (for editing posts from frontend) to have two different edit pages for two different post types. 
Here's the original function which handles the edit_link.

```
function wpuf_edit_post_link( $url, $post_id ) {
if ( is_admin() ) {
    return $url;
}

$override = wpuf_get_option( 'override_editlink', 'yes' );
if ( $override == 'yes' ) {
    $url = '';
    if ( wpuf_get_option( 'enable_post_edit' ) == 'yes' ) {
        $edit_page = (int) wpuf_get_option( 'edit_page_id' );
        $url = get_permalink( $edit_page );

        $url = wp_nonce_url( $url . '?pid=' . $post_id, 'wpuf_edit' );
    }
}

return $url;
}

add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'wpuf_edit_post_link', 10, 2 );
```

How can I call the current post parameters inside the function? I used `get_post` but it doesn't work (I guess because it's not inside the loop...). Here's the piece of function I edited. 201 and 203 are correct edit pages IDs: inside the pages there is some shortcode which turns them into an edit page.

```
$override = wpuf_get_option( 'override_editlink', 'yes' );
if ( $override == 'yes' ) {
    $url = '';
    if ( wpuf_get_option( 'enable_post_edit' ) == 'yes' ) {

    $post = get_post($post_id);

    if ($post->post_type == 'type1') {
        $url = get_permalink( 201 );
        $url = wp_nonce_url( $url . '?pid=' . $post_id, 'wpuf_edit' );
    }

    if ($post->post_type == 'type2') {
        $url = get_permalink( 203 );
        $url = wp_nonce_url( $url . '?pid=' . $post_id, 'wpuf_edit' );
    }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `$post = get_post($post_id);`, you can call `global $post;` which will load the value of the current post *assuming* that you have not triggered any other loops.

Comment: I have other loops in the page (on the sidebar)... but I put `wp_reset_postdata` at the end of the loops. Will this work? I'm trying rigth now.

Comment: no, it didn't work :( I tryed putting `global $post;` instead of `get_post` and also tryed to move it at the beginning of the function, but nothing :(

Comment: wait, I was doing a stupid mistake with `$url2` (it must be `$url` in both if statements), it works with `global $post;`, thanks Christopher! I edited the `$url` detail in my original post.